# Cobertura.ser file generation with Java Program

Tags: cobertura

Is it possible to generate "cobertura.ser" file with Java Program?

I could see that cobertura.ser is getting generated via cobertura maven plugin and I am able to read this file as below,

Sample service Class

```
public class SampleService {

public String sampleMethod(int a) {
    if(a==3) {
        return "equal";
    }
    else {
        return "notequal";
    }
}
}
```

Sample Test Class

```
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert; 

public class SampleServiceTest {

@Ignore
@Test
public void testSampleMethod1(){
    SampleService sampleService = new SampleService();
    String val = sampleService.sampleMethod(3);
    Assert.assertEquals("equal", val);
}

//@Ignore
@Test
public void testSampleMethod2(){
    SampleService sampleService = new SampleService();
    String val = sampleService.sampleMethod(5);
    Assert.assertEquals("notequal", val);
}

}
```

cobertura.ser reader class

```
import java.io.File;
import net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.ClassData;
import net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler;
import net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.ProjectData;

public class SampleCoberturaCoverage {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File dataFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Naren\\workspace\\cobsample\\target\\cobertura\\cobertura.ser");
    ProjectData projectData = CoverageDataFileHandler.loadCoverageData(dataFile);
    ClassData classData = projectData.getClassData("SampleService");
    System.out.println(classData.getNumberOfValidBranches());
  }
}
```

I require to generate the file with Java Program instead of running with Maven Plugin.